# Why does $\delta$ depend on $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

In my textbook on *metric spaces* by N.L. Carothers, the defintion for a continuous map is as follows (*slightly* modified by my professor from my lecture notes):

> Let $(M,d)$ and $(N,\rho)$ be metric spaces and $f : M \to N$. $f$ is continuous at $x \in M$ $\iff$ $\forall$ $\epsilon >0$ $\exists$ $\delta >0$ (which depends on $f$, $x$, and $\epsilon$) such that $d(x,y) < \delta$ $\implies$ $\rho(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$.

This definition is pretty standard, however, there is something that has recently been of question to me as I have gotten further in my studies: what does the author (and my professor) mean when they say $\delta$ depends on $f$? I understand that it depends on your choice of $x$ and $\epsilon$, but this is the only literature I have read where the author says that $\delta$ depends on $f$ as well. I have taken this for granted up until now, but I have been thinking about it a lot.

While uniform continuity is much stronger than continuity, this dependence of $\delta$ on $f$ makes an appearance again in their definitions (while on wikipedia, they state $\delta$ only depends on $\epsilon$):

> $f : M \to N$ is uniformly continuous $\iff$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists$ $\delta >0$ (which depends on $f$ and $\epsilon$ alone) such that $d(x,y) < \delta$ $\implies$ $\rho(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$.

If someone could clear this up for me, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $\delta$ didn't depend on $f$, then any proof that works for the continuity of $f$ at $x$ would work for the continuity of any other function $g$ at $x$.

Comment: yes each $\delta$ is dependent on the function in question, for example proving $y=x$ is continuous vs $y=x^2$ yields distinct $\delta$. Uniform drops the assumption of depending on the point and works throughout your domain independent of choice of point.I guess your answer is that the $\delta$ depends on the definition of your functions map, like when the text says the function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is defined VIA.....

Comment: Think about the functions $x$ and $x^2$ near the number $a = 10$.  If you want the function to vary at inputs near $10$ by at most $\varepsilon = 1/2$, then you'd better keep the input much closer to $10$ when you are looking at $x^2$ near $10$ then when you are looking at $x$ near $10$. Thus $\delta$ depends on the function, not just on $\varepsilon$ and $a$.

Comment: The dependence of $\delta$ on $f$ is made explicit in order to provide more clarity in the exposition of the concept of [equicontinuity of a family of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity).

Comment: When discussing continuity, the function $f$ is often considered fixed, so nobody bothers to say that $\delta$ depends on $f$. But, if for any reason you envision replacing $f$ by another function, then it is crucial to emphasize that $\delta$ depends on $f$ too!

Comment: @Ruy that makes sense! Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "usual" definition is

> Let $(M,d)$ and $(N,\rho)$ be metric spaces and $f : M \to N$. $f$ is continuous at $x \in M$ $\iff$ $\forall$ $\epsilon >0$ $\exists$ $\delta >0$  such that $d(x,y) < \delta$ $\implies$ $\rho(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$.

You say it is clear that $\delta$ will (in general) depend on $x$ and $\epsilon$. However, it is also clear that $\delta$ will depend on *all parameters* occurring in
$$d(x,y) < \delta \implies \rho(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon .$$
These are $x, \epsilon, f, d, \rho$. That is, if you take other metrics $\bar d$ on $M$, $\bar \rho$ on $N$ and another function $\bar f : M \to N$, you cannot expect that the same $\delta$ will do.

Usually the dependency on $f, d, \rho$ is not explicitly mentioned because the first sentence of the definition is "Let $(M,d)$ and $(N,\rho)$ be metric spaces and $f : M \to N$." This fixes these three parameters.

However, I am sure that you aware that this dependency exists. Think about the proof that the sum of two continuous real-valued functions $f_1, f_2 : M \to \mathbb R$ is again continuous. You certainly chose $\delta(x,\epsilon/2,f_1)$ and $\delta(x,\epsilon/2,f_2)$ and define $\delta(x,\epsilon,f_1+f_2) = \min (\delta(x,\epsilon/2,f_1),\delta(x,\epsilon/2,f_1))$.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you, Paul!